# Ranking in google sheets error. =rank(H2,$H2:$H92)+Countifs($H2=$H2,$I2,"<="&$I2)

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to rank schools by the collection year. If a school ties I would like to use a different column to break the tie. Here is the function that I put:

`=rank(H2,$H2:$H92)+Countifs($H2=$H2,$I2,"<="&$I2)`

I keep getting errors.

[image: 1]

Comment: What is that `countifs` doing? The `countifs` syntax seems to be all wrong I don't know what you are trying there.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The `RANK` function seems to be fine, the problem is with that `COUNTIFS` which I don't know what you are trying to do.

Usually when I need to RANK by two columns and they are both integers I just sum them up putting the secondary column as decimal.

So you would create another column, say you want to `RANK` by the column `A` then by `B` and they are both four digit years. Then you would need to create another column with the formula `A + B/1000`, then you just need to `RANK` by this new column.